# TableViewer with EMF databinding and cell editing - close but not quite

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-emf, tableviewer, eclipse-databinding

I am going through [Tom Shindl's instructions](http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2009/06/27/galileo-emf-databinding-part-5/) on how to add EMF databinding on to tables, here is my code for the data binding:

```java
protected DataBindingContext initDataBindings() {

    //going to use this person instead
    Person p = ProjectFactory.eINSTANCE.createPerson();
    p.setFirstName("tony");

    Committership c = ProjectFactory.eINSTANCE.createCommittership();
    c.setName("HELP");

    Committership anotherC = ProjectFactory.eINSTANCE.createCommittership();
    anotherC.setName("PELASE");

    Committership yetAnotherC = ProjectFactory.eINSTANCE.createCommittership();
    yetAnotherC.setName("EMERGENCY");

    p.getCommittership().add(c);
    p.getCommittership().add(anotherC);
    p.getCommittership().add(yetAnotherC);

    CommandStack cs = new BasicCommandStack();
    AdapterFactory af = new ProjectItemProviderAdapterFactory();
    EditingDomain editingDomain = new AdapterFactoryEditingDomain(af, cs);

    //data binding context
    DataBindingContext bindingContext = new DataBindingContext();
    //
    ObservableListContentProvider listContentProvider = new ObservableListContentProvider();
    IObservableMap[] attributeMap = new IObservableMap[1];
    attributeMap[0] = EMFEditProperties.value(
              editingDomain,
              FeaturePath.fromList(ProjectPackage.Literals.COMMITTERSHIP__NAME)
            ).observeDetail(listContentProvider.getKnownElements());

    TableViewerColumn column = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, SWT.NONE);
    column.getColumn().setText("First Name");
    column.getColumn().setWidth(200);
    column.setLabelProvider(new GenericMapCellLabelProvider("{0}", attributeMap));
    //tableViewer.setLabelProvider(new ObservableMapLabelProvider(attributeMap)); -- no need for this anymore
    tableViewer.setContentProvider(listContentProvider);

    //instead of giving it this list and doing it the non-EMF way
    IObservableList selfList = Properties.selfList(Person.class).observe(p.getCommittership());

    //property that you are looking for
    IListProperty prop = EMFEditProperties.list(editingDomain, ProjectPackage.Literals.PERSON__COMMITTERSHIP);
    IObservableValue master = EMFEditProperties.value(editingDomain, ProjectPackage.Literals.COMMITTERSHIP__NAME)
            .observe(p);

    /**this should not be returning null, instead it should be a
     *  list of the values from the person committership EList
     */
    IObservableList someList = prop.observeDetail(master);

    //set input requires and IObservableList!!
    tableViewer.setInput(someList);
    //
    return bindingContext;
}
```

ok, now just to talk through what is happening and where I am stuck.

this line here would work for JFace data binding:
`IObservableList selfList = Properties.selfList(Person.class).observe(p.getCommittership());`

it populates the table happily, it is a list containing the three people I added, nice.

now making it work with EMF databinding, I am trying this:

//property that you are looking for

```java
IListProperty prop = EMFEditProperties.list(editingDomain, ProjectPackage.Literals.PERSON__COMMITTERSHIP);
IObservableValue master = EMFEditProperties.value(editingDomain, ProjectPackage.Literals.COMMITTERSHIP__NAME)
        .observe(p);

/**this should not be returning null, instead it should be a
 *  list of the values from the person committership EList
 */
IObservableList someList = prop.observeDetail(master);
```

the problem is that `someList` is empty and hence he table won't populate, could someone explain why?
It is definitely those three line that have some logic problem in there.
What I really want is an `IObservableList` of observed EMF objects...

help would be really appreciated, since Shindl's tutorial doesn't explain where he go the master from...I thought I would create a master:

```java
IObservableValue master = EMFEditProperties.value(editingDomain, ProjectPackage.Literals.COMMITTERSHIP__NAME)
                .observe(p);
```

and do `prop.observeDetail(master)`

but it is returning an empty list as I mentioned above...if only I could at least get it do display the data, the closest I have come is having three cells but not data in them.

Answer (score 0):

```
IObservableList listObservable = prop.observe(p);
tableViewer.setInput(listObservable);
```

That fixed it for me in terms of viewing the data.

As for editing the cells, I did this in the end:

```
public class CommittershipNameEditingSupport extends EditingSupport {

    private static TableViewer tableViewer;
    private final CellEditor editor;

    public CommittershipNameEditingSupport(TableViewer tableViewer) {
        super(tableViewer);
        this.tableViewer = tableViewer;
        this.editor = new TextCellEditor(tableViewer.getTable());
    }

    @Override
    protected CellEditor getCellEditor(Object element) {
        return editor;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean canEdit(Object element) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object getValue(Object element) {
        return ((Committership) element).getName();
    }

    @Override
    protected void setValue(Object element, Object value) {
        ((Committership) element).setName(String.valueOf(value));
        tableViewer.update(element, null);
    }



}
```

and in the main view where I craeted the column I just added the method for cell editing support...it works nicely now :)